Cloud watch subscription filter pattern for log streams inside log group
I have a fluentbit cloudwatch log group,to which a subscription filter is attached. The destination is a kinesis firehose. The firehose, in turn, forwards logs to datadog. I want to limit the logs going into datadog to only the log streams I find relevant. I have been trying to figure out how to create a filter pattern on the subscription filter for this.
I tried something like this
%xyz*|abc*|efg*%. Where xyz,abc,efg are all strings in the different log streams of interest, in the log group which has the subscription filter.
This results in very few logs been streamed into firehose, when I know there are many more. I did use regex testing in the susbcription filter console. The logs are selected
But I feel, this is not the correct approach
I also changed log format to JSON and tried
{$.aws.awslogs.logStream="abc"}

But then I get an error stating
If a filter pattern starts with '{' it must end with '}'
I have been refering to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html
Question:
How do build a filter pattern to filter on log stream names?
Thanks
